# how to do urldeco on jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using the following but its not doing proper urldecoding for me

```
function showValues() {
                  var str = $j("form").serialize();
                  str = $j.URLDecode(str);
                  $j("#results").text(str);
}
```

how can I fix it

thanks

Comment: What is it outputting, and what are you inputting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? http://www.diveintojavascript.com/core-javascript-reference/the-decodeuri-function

It's a native javascript function that decodes a uri.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line to

```
 str =  unescape(str);
```